# x11 not working with SSH on virtual machine

Tags: ssh, virtual, virtualbox, x11

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on Oracle VirtualBox on a Windows 8 machine and whenever I try to display graphics while using SSH I get some error.  For example, in GNUPLOT:
    gnuplot> plot sin(x)

```
gnuplot: unable to open display ''
gnuplot: X11 aborted.
```

I've tried using mplayer and evince and I get similar errors.

I've tried changing `no` to `yes` in

```
#  Forwardx11 yes$
#  Forwardx11Trusted yes$
```

in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

I've been able to forward the graphics from the same machine onto another without problem so I know the problem must be local.
When I'm SSH'd in, `$DISPLAY` is blank

I've tried searching for solutions online, but I'm not finding much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using some X window server in your Window8 like Xming.
Have you tried to connect using "ssh -X name@machine"?

Comment: I've tried `ssh -X name@machine` ,
`ssh -Y name@machine`, and `ssh -XY name@machine`

Comment: I found my solution but forgot to post it:
I was using -x instead of -X